# BIOS int 10h service 0 and EGA mode

Tags: video, assembly, x86, dos, bios

I've spent a lot of time trying to find out what happens when one calls **BIOS INT 10**, service **0** to set video mode. Is it possible to perform these actions manually using EGA ports?

I've found documentation from different sources, but failed to find something that just sets particular mode. I'm starting to thing that a "video mode" is not just a register value, it's a bunch of settings in EGA.

To be clear, I'm practicing with text modes only (0,1,2,3 and 7) under DOSBox and QEMU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the web for `Tauron VGA Utilities`. The code in the package sets various video modes (text and graphics) using only the video registers and not using any BIOS functions. Most of these modes appear to work under DosBox, I just tried.